# Why are multiple page titles showing for one page in Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics, in the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report, it is listing multiple page titles for the same page path (primary dimension: page path; secondary: page title). For example:

Page: /my-page-path/
Page Title: "My page title"

Page: /my-page-path/
Page Title: "Some other page title for the same page"

Page: /my-page-path/
Page Title: "And so on..."

See what the table actually looks like in the screenshot linked below:

[See screenshot example from Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJoYY.png)

The page title hasn't changed this many times in the past 10 days, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on-topic for SE.

Comment: Isn't your page an SPA? In that case you might have different titles for different routes, but `document.location` which is the base for page path dimension will stay the same

Comment: The site is onepage type?